# Doesn not work audited 4.7 gem for updating model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, acts-as-audited

I am new to rails and I used [audited 4.7](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited) gem for my rails application to track loggers. I have no idea how do I add a comment to audit table record. thank you

Gemfile

```
gem "audited", "~> 4.7"
```

Model

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord

    audit
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# add to your Gemfile, and run bundle install to install it
gem "audited"

# install table for audited gem operation
rails generate audited:install
rails db:migrate

# open your model that you want to audited
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  audit
end
# restart rails server

# how to check the action 
@client = Client.first
@audits = @client.audits
if @audits
  @audits.each do |audit| 
    if audit.user
      audit.user.username
      audit.action
    end
  end              
end
```

Comment: thank you for answering. in my application audited working on a model. but only work with inserting and deleting a record. I want it to work with updating as well. In the default audit model there is a column as "comment". I want to add custom comment for logger. thank you

Comment: my understanding audit by default is working also with updating, see # how to check the action part in my answer, but previously you should do one record create and update and then check the action through audit.action

Comment: Thanks, now it is working with updating also. How do I add a comment ?

Comment: I answered your question above based from experience using audit gem to know who create/update the model, and I don't know how to use comment in audit, sorry